# I need to embed a Map (Google maps or any other) into my application

Tags: networking, google-maps, geocoding

Im on developing an application which shows a Region Map and the specific region blinks when the network is down for that area.

For example on the worldwide map, if India's network server is down , the application would highlight the India Map by highlighting it. How do i do this?

Any ideas please.. Its little urgent.

Comment: your application is developed in?

Comment: @Khurram : Application is being developed in Java jsp

Comment: Google Maps has JavaScript and Flash based API. Your best bet is JavaScript API; there are tutorials there as well...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript

Step by step tutorial: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/introduction.html

You will need to explore "Overlays"; you can draw polygons on map to emulate the required behavior